# Disable tap and hold in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is there a way to disable the tap **and hold** in an UITextView?

I currently have a subclass of UITextView which implements:

- **`caretRectForPosition:`**, which always returns `CGRectZero` to hide the caret
- **`addGestureRecognizer:`**, which is implemented to disable `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` gestures

**Next to to these methods I've also implemented `-canPerformAction:withSender:`, which just returns `NO`, but this method does not even get called (I've put a breakpoint there).**

Now everything works as I need it to work, but sadly the user can still **tap and hold** the textfield. This causes a magnifier to appear and also makes the textfield selectable. I've logged the attached gestures with `[self gestureRecognizers]` and received the following array:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x18e50b10>(
< UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x18f60a80; state = Possible; enabled = NO; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=pinFieldTapped:, target=<CDICPINWizardViewController 0x18f53ee0>)>>,
< UITextTapRecognizer: 0x18e344d0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=oneFingerTripleTap:, target=<UITextInteractionAssistant     0x18e34440>)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 3>,
< UITextTapRecognizer: 0x18e34610; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=oneFingerDoubleTap:, target=<UITextInteractionAssistant     0x18e34440>)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 2>,
< UITextTapRecognizer: 0x18e34740; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=twoFingerSingleTap:, target=<UITextInteractionAssistant     0x18e34440>)>; numberOfTouchesRequired = 2>,
< UITapAndAHalfRecognizer: 0x18e34870; state = Possible; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=tapAndAHalf:, target=<UITextInteractionAssistant 0x18e34440>)>>,
< UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x18e33830; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=twoFingerRangedSelectGesture:, target=<    UITextInteractionAssistant 0x18e34440>)>>,
< UITextTapRecognizer: 0x18e34a70; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=oneFingerTap:, target=<UITextInteractionAssistant     0x18e34440>)>>,
< UIVariableDelayLoupeGesture: 0x18e34b90; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <CDICTextField 0x18f55ff0>; target= <(action=loupeGesture:, target=<UITextInteractionAssistant     0x18e34440>)>>
)
```

Checking the array I do see all gestures report `enabled = NO`, except for the `UITapAndAHalfRecognizer` (which is not even a visible class to us developers).
Now I'm not sure if that gesture is the culprit. If so, I've got no idea how to disable that one as well.

I've searched SO for answers, but couldn't find one. Moreover the `-canPerformAction:withSender:` does not get called, which is probably because no action is being performed. The `UIMenuViewController` also isn't visible (I do not see the black bar with *Select/Copy/Paste* etc.), just a magnifier.

The `UIViewController` where the UITextField resides implements:

---

Again, what I *DO* want is:

- Make the UITextfield editable, but not selectable
- Disable all gestures (double tap, tap and hold, long press)

What I *DON'T* want is:

- The UITextField responding to select/copy/paste etc.
- Show a magnifier in any way

The reason as of 'why' is I'm making a sort of PIN-screen where I want the user to enter a number in the fields I want (since I'm bound to using textfields, please don't offer any other ways of creating a PIN-screen).

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass `UITextView` and override `canPerformAction:withSender`. Text fields that shouldn't provide copy/paste should be defined with your subclass.

**NonCopyPasteField.h:**

```
@interface NonCopyPasteField : UITextField
@end
```

**NonCopyPasteField.m:**

```
@implemetation
  (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(paste:)) {
      return NO;
    }
    [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
  }
@end
```

Let us know if you need any help of how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, but as I've stated in my question; that method _never_ gets called. If it was, I'd be happy (and probably done already).

Comment: Are you subclassing the UITextField?

Comment: I've subclassed UITextField and am using the subclass

Comment: It strange, that canPerformAction did not call. Maybe you did not set custom class in xib/storyboard?

Comment: Nope I've done that, happily using functions declared in my custom class. But the method still won't get called, I've even set a breakpoint in UITextfield's own implementation of `canPerformAction`..

Answer (score 1):

I`ve playing with pin input also. At now stopped at next in subclass:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}

-(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        NSInteger taps = ((UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer).numberOfTapsRequired;
        if (taps == 1) {
            gestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        }
    }

    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    return;
}
```

But in some cases text selection occurs.

Comment: Have you figured out something yet then?

Comment: Not yet, still use this. Works fine for my for my purposes.

Comment: Apple will re-enable some gestureRecognizers, so you actually need to override `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` instead.